# Reading a file in python issues

Tags: python

I am trying to read a CSV file in python using the following code:

```
with open(self.fileName, 'r') as openFile:
            dataReading = openFile.read()
        openFile.close()
        splitData = dataReading.split("\n")
        print splitDat
```

a
I don't understand why I am not getting any output.

`self.fileName` is meant to represent a file location on the computer, and I am attempting to open it and split it where there are new lines. Can somebody please assist me with the problem?

Comment: One thing, if you are using `with` you don't need to explicitly close the file after you exit that block.

Comment: What is `read_data`? Why do you close the file when `with` does that for you?

Comment: Use the `csv` module to read CSV files.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not getting any output - does it print `None`? An empty list? Does the script not run? Is there an error?

Comment: There is simply nothing. That is what I mean

Comment: If you put `print self.fileName` before the `with`, what does it output?

Comment: is the file you are reading empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the read line in `dataReading` and then doing `read_data.split()`

You might be intending to do this:

```
def convert(self):
        dataReading = []
        with open(self.fileName, 'r') as openFile:
            dataReading = openFile.readlines()
        for data in dataReading:
            print data
```

Comment: sorry, this was a mistake in copying it over, as i changed the variable names for easier reading. Despite this, I still get no ouput

Comment: "Easier reading" is when your code conforms to the [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are splitting at the new line character, but the code below should read in you file and print line by line (after split at the new line character).

```
with open(self.fileName, 'r') as openFile:
    for line in openFile:
        l_split = line.split('\n')
        print l_split
```